# Google static maps sem limite de url

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Queria criar uma imagem de varias rotas no google maps, já utilizei o encodepath para reduzir o tamanho do url, também tentei reduzir a definição dos pontos das coordenadas entre outras ideias que tive no entanto o que preciso é não ter nenhum impeditivo de caracteres.
Utilizar o html2canvas pode ser uma solução mas pelo facto de funcionar só no lado do cliente é impedimento para algumas funções que queria utilizar.
Deixo aqui uma imagem exemplo do que procuro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
A solução pode não ter que passar por usar o static maps, o que procuro mesmo são ideias para me ajudar a encontrar uma solução para o meu caso.
Obrigado

Comment: Mas o html2canvas é front-end, mas isso não o impede de subir ele pro servidor e salvar em uma imagem normal o resultado de `toDataURL`. Fora isto recomendo que explique o seu problema melhor, até entendi um pouco, mas não sei que limite é esse de URL, você se refere ao limite do HTTP via GET pra passar a querystring? Explique melhor por favor.

Comment: Uma das funções era gerar um pdf no servidor já com a imagem para enviar por email sem o cliente ter que ver a imagem no browser.
O limite que estou a falar é o url só suportar 2048 caracteres e como tenho muitos pontos ultrapassa esse limite. Consegui explicar-me? Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Sim conseguiu, mas a **dica** era pra você formular uma pergunta mais clara e não pra você explicar pra mim, entendeu? Não leve a mal, são apenas dicas que as vezes damos pra você tornar a sua questão mais clara, existem inúmeros tipos de limitações de tamanho, da maneira que escreveu na pergunta pode-se tirar inúmeras conclusões precipitadas e surgirem respostas que de nada irão lhe ajudar. =)